# what would you call someone that enjoy making friends

Tags: word-choice

I want the the one word that is used for someone that enjoy making friends.

Comment: There isn't just one word, there are several. And you may be interested in [ell.se] for future questions (read [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722) for more information about that).

Comment: Sociable, affable, an extrovert, socialite, outgoing, gregarious

Comment: Err... what's wrong with the obvious ***friendly**?*

Comment: Do you want a noun or an adjective? Please give an example sentence with a blank space where you would like to use this word.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **sociable**

> [Definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sociable):
>
> - inclined to associate with or be in the company of others.
> - friendly or agreeable in company; companionable.
> - characterized by agreeable companionship.

If the person doesn't like loneliness and needs company, you may say that he is "gregarious".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, ***friendship-oriented***

> *In general, Americans are slightly more friendship-oriented than Europeans and considerably more friendship-oriented than Asians or Africans.*
>
> [The "average American" book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=A-0hAAAAMAAJ&q=%22friendship+oriented%22&dq=%22friendship+oriented%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJitmelpvMAhWESBQKHXdmDSY4HhDoAQgrMAI) by [Barry Tarshis](http://authors.simonandschuster.com/Barry-Tarshis/1499904)
>
> *For example, women appear to be more friendship-oriented and practical as well as less game-playing in their love styles than do men. Men are more inclined toward casual sexuality than are women.*
>
> [The Handbook of Sexuality in Close Relationships](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qsl4AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA177&dq=%22friendship+oriented%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_eScmJvMAhVH0xQKHXacDLM4HhDoAQg4MAQ#v=onepage&q=%22friendship%20oriented%22&f=false)